# MongoSkin can't increment by one

Tags: mongodb

I'm having a difficult time trying to increment a value by one using MongoSkin.

```
var client = mongoskin.db( // mongodb://server/database?options
    'mongodb://localhost/database?auto_reconnect=true&poolSize=1',
    {safe: true}
);
```

I add the following object (document) to my database - I've verified the object is in the database and can use $set to update.

{loginCount: 0}

When I attempt to update the loginCount nothing happens.

```
client.collection("user").findOne(user_id.toString(), 
    {$set: { $inc: { loginCount: 1 }}}, function (err, data) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue:

```
client.collection("users").updateById(
  user_id.toString(),
  $inc: {loginCount: 1},
  $set: {anotherfield: anothervalue},
  function (err) {
    // handle error here
  }
}
```

The $set operator is used independently of the $inc operator. It seems that $inc, will increment and set the value.